# Any issue/problem with coefficient of 1.00 (one) for MA part of the ARIMA(1,0,1) model with regressors

Tags: r, regression, time-series, forecasting, arima

I fitted an ARIMA(1,0,1) model with regressors in R and obtained the coefficient of AR to be -0.515 with standard error of 0.1845 and that of the MA coefficient to be 1.000 with standard error of 0.2164. This means both the AR and the MA parts are significant. (I omitted the coefficients for the regressors here for simplicity).

My Question:

1) Methodologically/practically, is there any issue/problem having a coefficient of the MA part to be 1.000 (one) in 
a) ARIMA with regressors? 
b) ARIMA without regressors?

2) Generally, is there any issue to have a coefficient of AR or MA part to be 1 (one)?